# Sharepoint 2010: Associate Workflow Dynamically with List using VS2012

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a custom list and  a task list using VS2012. Now In the same solution I am creating a workflow, I want to associate the workflow with the list and the task list but I don't see the name in list dropdown on creating workflow. Is there any way to associate with the list? On running app, I don't want to add workflow for the list manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event receiver to your feature by right clicking on your feature in VS solution explorer.

Since you are using a site collection feature, In the feature activated handler get a reference to your library:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
     SPSite site = (SPSite) properties.Feature.Parent;
     SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
     SPList list = web.Lists["Name of the Document Library"];
}
```

this assumes your web is the root site collection web you can then call the following method:

```
public void EnsureWorkflowAssociation(SPList list, string workflowTemplateName, string associationName, bool allowManual, bool startCreate, bool startUpdate)
        {
            var workflowAssociation =
                list.WorkflowAssociations.Cast<SPWorkflowAssociation>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == associationName);
            if (workflowAssociation!=null)
            {
                list.WorkflowAssociations.Remove(workflowAssociation);
                list.Update();
            }

            var web = list.ParentWeb;
            var lcid = (int)web.Language;
            var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo(lcid);

            var template = web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName(workflowTemplateName, defaultCulture);
            var association = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(template, associationName,
                                    web.Lists[Lists.Tasks.Description()],
                                   web.Lists[Lists.WorkflowHistory.Description()]
                                                                   );
            association.AllowManual = true;
            association.AutoStartChange = true;
            association.AutoStartCreate = true;

            list.WorkflowAssociations.Add(association);
            list.Update();


            association = list.WorkflowAssociations[association.Id];
            association.AllowManual = allowManual;
            association.AutoStartChange = startUpdate;
            association.AutoStartCreate = startCreate;
            association.AssociationData = "<Dummy></Dummy>";
            association.Enabled = true;
            list.WorkflowAssociations.Update(association);
            list.Update();

        }
```

*workflowTemplateName* should be the name of your workflow

*associationName* a name that you must pick for the association

Comment: which event receiver?

Comment: You can add an event receiver to your feature that will run some code after the feature is activated. In solution explorer right click on your feature and add event receiver

Comment: What type of feature are you using to create the lists? Site? Web?

Comment: Site...How to pass SPList? I tried different ways but always getting object reference error

Comment: How can I debug the code? On running app, I am getting error "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Value cannot be null."

Comment: Attach debugger to all IIS working processes, and enable the feature using the browser. You can set a break point inside your feature activated handler and step through. To make it easier install this Visual Studio Add on: http://cksdev.codeplex.com/ it has a shortcut to attach to all IIS Processes automatically

Comment: What namespace required for "Lists.Tasks.Description()"? I am getting "The name 'Lists' does not exist in the current context" error